# Download dialog Box IE

Tags: vba, microsoft-ui-automation

I have use this code

[Controlling IE11 "Do you want to Open/Save" dialogue window buttons in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145437/controlling-ie11-do-you-want-to-open-save-dialogue-window-buttons-in-vba)

But I get the error

> "user defined type not defined"

on

```
Dim o As IUIAutomation
```

Someone knows how  can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to add a project reference to the UI Automation library. At least I could reproduce your error and fix it by adding the reference.

[image: UI Automation Client]

Answer (score 0):

Add it using code

```
Public Sub AddReference()

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile 
"C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll"

End Sub
```

and goto excel>>option>>Trust Center>>Trust Center Setting>>Macro setting  and check on the Trust access to the VBA project object model