# VBA to choose "save" option on download on IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, download, save

I'm using VBA to open an Internet Explorer window, navigate and log into a webpage and download an Excel Spreadsheet. Every bit of the process works fine, but I can't find a way to automate the process of choosing the "save" option everytime I try to download something on IE.

Here's the code I've been using, found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145437/controlling-ie11-do-you-want-to-open-save-dialogue-window-buttons-in-vba), I know I can set VBA to send Alt+S automatically, but it won't work when IE is not in focus and I just couldn't find a way on the web that works.

```
AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
```

Is there another way to do it? Without Sending Keys? Or a working way to send keys?

I appreciate any help!

Observations: I'm using IE 11 and can't tinker with it's settings, because I'm not the administrator.

Comment: How is the download triggered?

Comment: It clicks on an image with a specific id: `objIE.document.getElementById("formE:j_idt945").Click`
And then it asks me if i want to open or save it.

Comment: It may be that there's an easier way to download the file, but with the relevant source from the page it's hard to know.  If there's a URL in there which points directly to the download then `Workbooks.Open(theURL)` is easier to implement.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you're saying, but I don't think it can be done :(  
`<a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('formE'),{'formE:j_idt944':'formE:j_idt944'},'');return false"><img id="formE:j_idt945" src="/Sip/resources/img/nissan/bt-print1.png?pfdrid_c=true" alt="" width="50" height="25"></a>`

I think it's calling a javascript function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145437/controlling-ie11-do-you-want-to-open-save-dialogue-window-buttons-in-vba has a Windows API-based approach.